# Liferay Search static text within all portlets

Tags: search, liferay, liferay-6

I would like to know if built in functionality exists or how to implement functionality to search the static text of JSPs not web content of all deployed portlets in liferay from a centralised portlet (or theme). Unfortunately, there does not seem to be help regarding this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: issue? what is the issue here? What exactly do you want to achieve and what exactly is your requirement?

Comment: I would like to search my static text from jsps so that the user can click the result and go to a page

Comment: what do you mean by 'static text of JSPs' ? If you want to search text content, then you should use web content anyway.

Comment: I mean the text from jsps, as my site has some portlets which does not make use of web content

Comment: So, this jsp-text is data that is not stored in your database, right ? Maybe this feature is not a good idea, to start with ?

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Developing+portlets+with+improved+SEO+capabilities) could be helpful. You must get rid of long and ugly URLs and use Liferay API's mentioned in that Wiki.

Comment: Is there a way to automate this such as a meta tag which is picked up by liferay? I find it strange that the developer has programmatically add such terms. Thanks